# On Mac OS X, why would a network folder appear dimmed, and not be accessible?

Tags: macos, ntfs

I have a user who is using a Mac to connect to our corporate network.  He is attaching to a DFS share on a Windows Server 2003 machine using the IP address.  He created a folder a few weeks ago that has 800+ MBs of data in it.  Now, whenever he selects the folder, he cannot see the contents of the folder, instead he sees a "Preview" pane showing the name of the folder, the size of the folder, etc.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Any idea how to allow him to see the contents of the folder?  I've already checked that he has NTFS perfmissions on the folder, and I (and other users) can see the contents of the folder using standard domain user accounts.

Comment: Tip: when taking screen shots, you can press [space] after starting the shot and click on the window or UI element of interest to focus on it.

Comment: Answer the question with that answer, rather than commenting with it. *look below*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I could not find any way to resolve this, I simply made a copy of the folder, then used Cut-and-Paste to move the contents over to the new folder. I then renamed the old folder as 'Old Folder', and renamed the new folder 'Images New Website' (the name of the original folder).